# SSL Handshake Error when writing AI analysis results to MongoDB Atlas from AWS lambda

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, ssl, aws-lambda, pymongo

I've been working on a project involving concurrent AI processing of around 100 videos using AWS Lambda. The results of this analysis are being written to a MongoDB Atlas database. For the most part, the process works smoothly and the results are successfully written to the database. However, I'm encountering an issue with a few videos where the following error occurs:

`SSL handshake failed: <MongoDB Atlas URL>: EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:1131)`

Has anyone else encountered this specific error while working with MongoDB Atlas? Or do you have any insights into what might be causing this SSL handshake failure?